# How to select a radio button by default in formly form angularjs

Tags: angular-formly

How do I set "onDemand" as default when the form is loaded? 
(Background: There is a hidden text box which should only be visible when "Predefine" is checked. Unfortunately, it is visible when the form gets loaded first. At this point I thought about making the onDemand checked by default to keep the textbox invisbile at first page load)

```
{"key":"discountType","type":"radioType", "templateOptions":{"options":   [{"name":"OnDemand","value":"OnDemand"},{"name":"Predefined","value":"Predefine"}]}},
                        {"key":"discValue","type":"input","templateOptions": {"type":"input"}, hideExpression: "model.discountType=='OnDemand'"}  
                    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did some trial and error after sleeping over it and I got it. 
discount.discountInfo.discType="OnDemand"; resolved it.

```
var discount = this;
discount.title = title;
discount.discountInfo = {};
discount.fields=[{"key":"discountType","type":"radioType", "templateOptions":{"options":   [{"name":"OnDemand","value":"OnDemand"},{"name":"Predefined","value":"Predefine"}]}},
                    {"key":"discValue","type":"input","templateOptions": {"type":"input"}, hideExpression: "model.discountType=='OnDemand'"}  
                ]
discount.discountInfo.discType="OnDemand";
```